# Babel Plugin callback when all files have been processed?

Tags: plugins, babeljs

I'm trying to call a method when all files have been processed in a babel plugin but I'm having trouble doing so.  There are `pre()` and `post()` methods that are called for every file passed into a plugin but I'd like a callback to run when ALL files have finished processing or... after ALL `post()`'s have finished running.

Is there a hook that I can use or is it possible for me to see how many files have been passed to my plugin for processing (so that I can keep track myself)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Babel's plugin system is entirely per-file currently. Babel itself has no way of knowing that multiple files are being processed, or that they are finished, so it has no way of passing that information down into a plugin.

Comment: I was going to ask this exact question. Is this still not possible by now? I noticed that the `state` argument passed to `pre()` and `post()` contains useful info like `opts.sourceFileName`, `opts.cwd` and other cmd-line parameters. Would it be possible in the future that we could have `opts.fileCount` with the total number of files being processed?

Comment: @GetFree The hard part is that Babel just isn't guaranteed to have that information. Take Webpack for example. At the time that Babel runs, Webpack hasn't processed the file to decide what other dependencies it has, so even Webpack doesn't know all the files in the project yet.